# tomcat vs FULL J2EE Solutions

Tags: tomcat

We are getting ready to make a major revision in our Web Application architecture which currently is running on JBoss 4.2.  At first we were looking at moving from 4.2 to JBoss 6 but after some research tomcat may be a better solution for us.

My first question is their anything that JBoss can do that tomcat cannot do assuming you are using the correct plugins.  We do not really use EJB's in our solution and it would appear there are simple plugins for web services, JMX and other features.

Tomcat appears to have much better support, faster upgrade cycles and many, many books.

Since there is less to the system it also seems much easier to support from an admin point of view.

What am I missing?

The main features we want to enable are better clustering support and session replication / persistence.

We will consider other application servers as well such as Glassfish / Geronimo.

quote form a web article:

**Apache Tomcat is the world’s most widely used web application server, with over one million downloads per month and over 70% penetration in the enterprise datacenter.  Tomcat is used to power everything from simple one server sites to large enterprise networks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed complex J2EE applications running on Tomcat that were later migrated to Oracle BEA Weblogic so I think Tomcat can support most of your needs. But only you can decide based on the requirements of your application.

Here are some links that might give more insight to make this decision.

http://www.slideshare.net/OpenLogic/comparison-of-open-source-app-servers-final-presentation
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2007/jw-12-appservers.html

Comment: +1 for the Javaworld article, the comparison table is helpful.  You'll find Tomcat to have a nice startup speed compared to full EE application servers.